# AC-3 Codec - no audio

Tags: android, media-player, video-player

I'm playing a video using BetterVideoPlayer but video is playing but no audio is coming out. As i analysed, i found that this video is using AC-3 Codec(May be).

Google's Video player have also the same behaviour, but MX Player is also to play that video perfectly.